# What is the proper way to refer to resource directory path in one source set in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my build.gradle file, I have defined a separate sourceSet for integration tests:

```
sourceSets {
    integtest {
        java.srcDir 'src/integtest/java/io/attil/integration'
        resources.srcDir 'src/integtest/resources'
    }
}
```

I would like to use the path to resources of the integration tests in one of my manually defined tasks (a task that prefills the data-base for integration tests; the sql script is located in the mentioned resource folder).

I have now the following solution:

```
task prefillDatabase {
    // ... snip!

        String sqlString = new File(sourceSets.integtest.resources.srcDirs.iterator().next().toString() + '/setup_integration_tests.sql').text


    // ... snip!
}
```

While this works, it is quite cumbersome.

Is there a better, shorter way to achieve the same? (I'm looking for something like `sourceSets.integtest.resources.srcDir`.)

Comment: If you're ready to assume that there is only one element in the set, why not just store it in a property, reference that property when defining the sourceSet and in your prefillDatabase task?

Comment: That said, you should just be able to do sourceSets.integtest.resources.first()

Comment: Good point about `first()`, that makes it a little bit shorter :) I had thought about the other possibility too (property), but I wonder, if this is the 'best practice'?

Comment: I would say that the best way would be to use a property for the directory location: your prefillDatabase task shouldn't suddenly break if you later decide to add a second resource directory for your tests. Maybe the SQL file shouldn't even be in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is less verbose, but I'd argue it's more correct

```
File file = sourceSets.integtest.resources.matching {
    include 'setup_integration_tests.sql'
}.singleFile

String sqlString = file.text
```

See [FileTree.matching(Closure)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileTree.html#matching%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) and [FileCollection.getSingleFile()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#getSingleFile%28%29)

Also, this looks wrong to me

```
java.srcDir 'src/integtest/java/io/attil/integration'
```

I'd think it would be

```
java.srcDir 'src/integtest/java'
java.include 'io/attil/integration/**'
```